# Introductory metric spaces problem (inequality)

Tags: metric-spaces

Problem: Given a metric space $(X, d)$, prove that $\mid d(x,z) - d(y,u)\mid \leq d(x,y) + d(z,u)   ,  (x,y,z,u \in X)$.

The only thing I could think to use was the triangle inequality for each of $d(x,z)$ and $d(y,u)$, which gave me $d(x,z) + d(y,u) \leq d(x,y) + d(z,u) + 2d(y,z)$. I tried a few different things from that point, nothing worked however. I'm probably missing something fairly straightforward, can anyone help?

Comment: $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,u)+d(u,z)$. This proves one part. Similarly, you can prove the other part also.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y)  + d(y,u)  + d(u,z)$ by the triangle inequality. Hence, $d(x,z) - d(y,u) \leq d(x,y) + d(u,z)$.

Similarly,
$d(y,u) \leq d(y,x)  + d(x,z)  + d(z,u)$ by the triangle inequality. Hence, $d(y,u) - d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(u,z)$.

From the above two statements, it follows that $|d(y,u) - d(x,z)| \leq d(x,y) + d(u,z)$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $d(x,z) \geq d(y,u)$:

$$d(x,z) - d(y,u) \leq d(x,y) + d(z,u) = d(x,y) + d(u,z) \Rightarrow d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,u) + d(u,z)$$
we know that $d(x,u) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,u)$ (triangle inequality):

$$d(x,u) + d(u,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,u) + d(u,z)$$
And we know $d(x,z) \leq d(x,u) + d(u,z)$ (triangle inequality). So,
$$d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,u) + d(u,z)$$

You can do this for the other case ($d(x,z) < d(y,u)$).